# How to prevent text overlap on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is a simple program designed to grab server latency, project it, and refresh it on a small canvas, however I am unable to find a way to find a way to prevent text overlap, and the new ping remains superimposed over the old ping.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import subprocess
import time

host = "141.101.115.212" #host IP address

master = Tk()

im = Image.open("image.png")
width, height = im.size
canvas = Canvas(master, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)


def display():

    x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    x = str(x.communicate()[0])
    lhs, rhs = x.split("Average = ")
    lhs, rhs = rhs.split("\\", 1)
    print(lhs)

    latency = lhs

    text = canvas.create_text(40, 100, anchor=NW)
    canvas.itemconfig(text, text=latency, width=width)
    canvas.itemconfig(text, font=("courier", 70, "bold"))
    canvas.itemconfig(text, fill="white")

    master.after(100, display)

    #time.sleep(1)
    #canvas.delete(text)
    #canvas.update()
    print("iteration")

master.after(0, display)
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new text item every time. Instead, just change the text of the old item.

```
canvas.itemconfigure(text, text=new_latency)
```

Your other option is to delete the old item before creating the new item, but it's better just to reuse the old item.

Comment: I'm curios, does `master.after(100, display)` means that the function display will be called every 100 milliseconds i.e. 1/10th of a second? Because it seems to take longer to me.

Comment: It means that it will be called _as soon as possible_ after 100 ms have passed.

Comment: @user4261180, please mark answer accepted so other people reviewing the question list  will know that this is answered correctly (which it is).

Comment: @BryanOakley How do I do that?

Comment: @user4261180: how do you do what? My answer shows how to change the text. What more do you need?

Comment: @user4261180: click on the checkmark under the votes. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer